# Python bit.ly link wordlist generator

Tags: python, generator, bit.ly, word-list

I've been developing a Python tool to generate a bit.ly wordlist. Here are the particularities of bit.ly links:

- Contain 7 entities
- Begin with a number (generally 3 or 2)
- End with a letter
- Can't have the same entity side by side

I already did the first 3 conditions, but I can't find a way to do the last.

```py
from itertools import product

def firstN(chars, length):
    for firstNumber in product(chars, repeat=length):
        yield ''.join(firstNumber)

def combiwords(chars, length):
    for letters in product(chars, repeat=length):
        yield ''.join(letters)

def lastL(chars, length):
    for lastLetter in product(chars, repeat=length):
        yield ''.join(lastLetter)

def main():
    firstNumber = "32"
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    lastLetter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    for wordlen1 in range(1, 2):
        for first in firstN(firstNumber, wordlen1):
            for wordlen2 in range(6, 7):
                for combo in combiwords(letters, wordlen2):
                    for wordlen3 in range(1, 2):
                        for word in lastL(lastLetter, wordlen3):
                            print('https://bit.ly/' + first + combo + word)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood. You want to generate all the possible strings composed by 7 elements, starting with a number, ending with a letter and not having the same element repeated subsequentially?

Comment: More detailed informations:
I want to generate all the possible strings composed by 7 elements, like marte said, but if there is the same element side-by-side, i want it to change, more like to continue to the other element (eg. "aa" go to "ba" and not outputing the first string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I wrote a couple of functions which can solve your problem:

```
import random
import string

def generate_alphanumeric_string_without_sequential_repetitions():
    # string.ascii_lowercase means 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'. If you need it to be case unsensitive, change this to string.ascii_lowercase
    allowed_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    allowed_chars = allowed_letters + '0123456789'
    
    result = random.choice(allowed_chars) # init first char of the sequence
    
    # generate characters (which must be alphanumeric) in positions [1,5]
    for i in range(1, 5):
        random_char = random.choice(allowed_chars)
        
        # avoid sequential repetitions by re-generating a char if is the same of the previous one
        while random_char == result[i-1]:
            random_char = random.choice(allowed_chars)
        
        result = result + random_char
        
    # generate last char (which must be a letter)
    last_char = random.choice(allowed_letters)
    
    # avoid sequential repetitions by re-generating last char if is the same of the previous one
    while last_char == result[-1]: # result[-1] is a trick in python for getting the last char of a string
        last_char = random.choice(allowed_letters)

    return result + last_char


def generate_string():
    return str(random.randint(0, 9)) + generate_alphanumeric_string_without_sequential_repetitions()
```

## Results

With the following code executed

```
random.seed(10)

result = list()

for i in range(0, 10):
    result.append(generate_string())
    
print(result)
```

I've had the following result:

```
['9c14ano', '7rkc75k', '1pxc0it', '5y0sq3f', '4xi3p2t', '6capimj', '8xpu92n', '7eu6kon', '3c5te8c', '2yxjhgo']
```

If you have any questions, just ask in the comments. I hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are searching for:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/

```
def removeUtil(string, last_removed):
 
    # If length of string is 1 or 0
    if len(string) == 0 or len(string) == 1:
        return string
 
    # Remove leftmost same characters
    # and recur for remaining
    # string
    if string[0] == string[1]:
        last_removed = ord(string[0])
        while len(string) > 1 and string[0] ==
                                    string[1]:
            string = string[1:]
        string = string[1:]
 
        return removeUtil(string, last_removed)
 
    # At this point, the first
    # character is definiotely different
    # from its adjacent. Ignore first
    # character and recursively
    # remove characters from remaining string
    rem_str = removeUtil(string[1:], last_removed)
 
    # Check if the first character
    # of the rem_string matches
    # with the first character of
    # the original string
    if len(rem_str) != 0 and rem_str[0] ==
                                         string[0]:
        last_removed = ord(string[0])
        return (rem_str[1:])
 
    # If remaining string becomes
    # empty and last removed character
    # is same as first character of
    # original string. This is needed
    # for a string like "acbbcddc"
    if len(rem_str) == 0 and last_removed ==
                                   ord(string[0]):
        return rem_str
 
    # If the two first characters of
    # str and rem_str don't match,
    # append first character of str
    # before the first character of
    # rem_str.
    return ([string[0]] + rem_str)
 
def remove(string):
    last_removed = 0
    return toString(removeUtil(toList(string),
                                    last_removed))
 
# Utility functions
def toList(string):
    x = []
    for i in string:
        x.append(i)
    return x
 
def toString(x):
    return ''.join(x)
```

Store your current output to a list (eg `wl`)

```
wl.append('https://bit.ly/' + first + combo + word)
```

and after your loop run `remove` over every entry.